How many ways are there to write a positive integer as a sum of consecutive squares?

How many ways are there to write a given positive integer $n$ as a sum of consecutive square integers?

Is there a slick way to answer this question in general? I initially thought not, and wrote a program to iteratively find every possibility. But recently I learned about the politeness of a number, and that the number ways of writing a positive integer as a sum of consecutive positive integers (not squares) is the same as the number of odd divisors of that number. Is there a similarly slick way to enumerating all the ways of writing an integer as a sum of consecutive squares?
Relevant OEIS Sequences

A034705 – Numbers that are sums of consecutive squares.
A130052 – Numbers that are the sum of consecutive squares in more than one way.
A234304 – Numbers with at least 3 representations as a sum of consecutive squares.

Also notable is that A298467, the smallest positive integer that can be expressed as the sum of consecutive positive squares in exactly $k$ ways, lists 554503705 for $k=4$, but has no fifth entry.

Interesting question and now I'm curious too. $9 = 2+3+4 = 4+5$ because $ 5 = 2+3$. But for squares you need to figure out when many small consecutive squares can sum to the same sum as a few big squares. I can't even think of any examples. Did you find any examples in your program? Just wondering.
Like $n^2 + m^2  = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ where $n$ and $m$ are consecutive integers and $a, b,$ and $c$ are consecutive integers. Obviously there can be bigger combinations than $2$ and $3$ too, but I can't think of any myself.

So you're asking to solve for $(a-b)(2a^2 + 2ab+3a+2b^2+3b+1 ) = 6n$, or with $ a = b+k$, $k(6b^2 + 6bk+6b+2k^2 + 3k + 1 ) = 6n$. For each $k$ divisor of $6n$, you'd have to check if the quadratic allows for integer $b$ as a root when set to $6n/k$.

The most relevant OEIS entry is A296338 which gives the number of partitions of $n$ into consecutive positive squares.
